# Need to add a new complaint to my site using django, but don't understand how to

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I need to add new complaint to my complaint management site but I don't understand how to. I tried using the class Createview but the form is not rendering to the template. What should I do? WHat do I need to add to my code?

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.deletion import CASCADE
class Complaints(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= CASCADE, null = True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    description = models.TextField(null=True, blank= True)
    highpriority = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    document = models.FileField(upload_to='static/documents')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

views.py:

```
class ComplaintCreate(CreateView):
    model = Complaints
    field = '__all__'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('New')
    template_name = 'new.html'
```

template:

```
  <!-- Middle Container -->
    <div class="col-lg middle middle-complaint-con">
        <i class="fas fa-folder-open fa-4x comp-folder-icon"></i>
        <h1 class="all-comp">New Complaint</h1>

        <form class="" action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {% csrf_token %}
            <div class="form-control col-lg-10 comp-title-field"> {{form.title}} </div>
            <p class="desc">Description</p>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary preview-btn">Preview</button>
            <textarea class="form-control comp-textarea" rows="7" placeholder="Enter text here"></textarea>
            <button type="file" name="myfile" class="btn btn-secondary attach-btn"><i class="fas fa-file-upload"></i> Attachment</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary save-btn" value="submit"><i class="fas fa-save"></i> Save</button>
        </form>

    </div>
```

this is my urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('Home/', landing_page.views.landing, name= 'Home'),
path('Registration/', accounts.views.RegisterPage),
path('Login/', accounts.views.LoginPage, name='Login'),
path('Login/Profile/', accounts.views.profile, name='Profile'),
path('Logout/', accounts.views.LogoutUser, name='Logout'),
path('Login/Add-Complaint', accounts.views.newcomplaint, name = 'New')
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

[image: This is how my new complaint page looks. But the title form I tried to add is not accepting any input. Ik I might be way off in my code. But I don't understand what else to add]

The form is accepting inputs now but the complaints aren't getting saved in the admin panel anymore

Comment: `field` -> `fields`

Comment: It still isn't accepting any inputs

Comment: What is the error you're getting?

Comment: there's no error but the title field isn't accepting anything, like I am even unable to type in anything in it

Comment: Can you add the code for 'accounts.views.newcomplaint'.

Comment: There's not much in that:  `def newcomplaint(request):
    return render(request, 'new.html', {})`

Comment: You don't need to create your own function based view, if you're already using class based view. 

In urls.py, replace `accounts.views.newcomplaint` -> `views.ComplaintCreate.as_view()`


e.g 


`path('Login/Add-Complaint', views.ComplaintCreate.as_view() , name = 'New')`

Comment: I did that but now it shows the ModuleNotFound error: `from tcs_backend.accounts.views import ComplaintCreate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tcs_backend.accounts'`

Comment: Umm, make sure your modules are created properly(e.g there should be `__init__.py` file in tcs_backend and accounts folder)

Comment: It does... and its also added in the settings folder

Comment: Oh ok, It's done! I found the error... I had a spelling error while importing the file